# Replace string in JavaScript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a string (`/\`) in JavaScript with Forward slash (`/`).

For example, this: `uploads/\images\cats\rr.jpg` should become this: `uploads/imagescats/rr.jpg`

I tried `string.replace(/\\/g,"");` but is replacing only `\` backslash.

And also, I tried replace `\` with `/`

Anyone have an idea how I can replace this symbols? I don't understand regex very well.

Comment: You need to include the *escaped* forward slash in the regex. `s.replace(/\/\\/g, "/")` Keep in mind that the first and last `/` are just delimiters that indicate the start and end of the regex grammar.

Comment: ...I assume it's the sequence of "/\" that you're trying to replace.

Comment: this is my string uploads/\images\cats\rr.jpg and i wanna receive this uploads/images/cats/rr.jpg

Comment: If the rule is a "/\" or a "\" becomes "/", then `s = s.replace(/\/?\\/g, "/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rule is a `"/\"` or a `"\"` becomes `"/"`, then use this regex: `s = s.replace(/\/?\\/g, "/")`.

It looks for a backslash, optionally preceded by a forward slash, and replace it (or them) with a single forward slash.

```js
const s = "uploads/\\images\\cats\\rr.jpg";
const res = s.replace(/\/?\\/g, "/");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include `\/` in your regex and make it a charecter class.

```
string.replace(/[\\\/]/g,"");
```

Comment: thanks, works, but i receive  uploads//images/cats/rr.jpg. so i use this instead s.replace(/\/?\\/g, "/") -- thanks to  Skinny Pete